# CRTP and static member initialization

Tags: c++

When I compile the following

```
template <typename Derived> struct Bar 
{
     static inline constexpr int x = Derived::value;
};

struct Foo : Bar<Foo>
{
    static inline constexpr int value = 101;
};
```

I get a compile error using VS 2019 16.6

```
Source.cpp(5,47): error C2039: 'value': is not a member of 'Foo'
Source.cpp(8): message : see declaration of 'Foo'
Source.cpp(9): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'Bar<Foo>' being compiled
Source.cpp(5,1): error C2065: 'value': undeclared identifier
Source.cpp(5,1): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
Source.cpp(5,1): message : a non-constant (sub-)expression was encountered
```

So is it illegal to true to initialize a static from a CRTP derived class or is the compiler wrong?
I certainly find the error "'value': is not a member of 'Foo'" odd as value clearly is a member.

Comment: It compiles with gcc and clang http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a22d8a0475a8faa1

Comment: I'm not sure how this could possibly work, since at the point where `Bar<Foo>` is instantiated, `Foo` is incomplete and does not yet have a member `value`.

Comment: Hmm... following @NicolBolas comment I'm not so sure it's MSVC bug. Other cases that involve using incomplete type in CRTP fail also with gcc and clang: https://godbolt.org/z/hfPcr7

Comment: @NicolBolas [I don't believe the definitions of the members of a class template are instantiated at the same time as the template.](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.inst-3.1) So `Bar<Foo>::x = Foo::value` isn't supposed to matter until you ask for `Bar<Foo>::x`, and as long as `Foo` and `Foo::value` exist by that time, you're fine. [Note that I can fully *remove* `Foo::value` and both Clang and GCC compile the code fine](https://godbolt.org/z/x31v5h).

Comment: @AmirKirsh That's because the *declarations* of the members are required to compile when the class template is implicitly specialized, but their definitions don't have to work yet. In your case `Foo::Type` is needed for the declaration of `Bar<Foo>::x` (it's the type), so it fails when `Foo` doesn't have it. (EDIT: Perhaps `constexpr` should be changing things, however...)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Given there seems to be debate about if it should work and that GCC and Clang compile it I will submit it as an MSVC issue and see what they do. I would agree thought that I don't think this is a time of instantiation issue.

Comment: @goneskiing I already submitted a bug when first saw your question: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1110270/crtp-in-msvc-1924-not-seeing-variable.html

Comment: @HTNW your point is well taken, adding to the "lazy instantiation" of definition vs. declaration - using Derived::Type in the definition side works fine: https://godbolt.org/z/TKqTYv

Comment: Amir you beat me to it but I had already submitted as well! I added comments to both VS Community issues linking them.

Comment: So if this is a bug in VC is there a nice work around? I could add a int template paramter to Bar and "pass" the integer value up but this makes the definition of Bar uglier.

Comment: So I did find a not to ubgly work around. I created a type trait class containing th value so, "struct Trait<Foo> { static inline constexpr int value { 101 };" and then use that in the Bar class